How to forward specific traffic between two interfaces in one machine RHEL8
OS: RHEL8.
Goal: Forward SIP and RTP from VM main interface(ens192) to virtual manually created(ens100)
For Testing I trying to forward only ICMP packets, but it's not working.
(VM1) --icmp--> ens192(VM2) --forward-icmp--> ens100(VM2)

Interface was created by command:
nmcli connection add type macvlan dev ens192 ifname ens100 mode bridge ethernet.cloned-mac-address 00:50:56:95:19:67 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 1.1.1.1
forwarding enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
enabled masquaring firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
two interfaces in one zone firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward --permanent
add rule for icmp firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-protocol=icmp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --list-all

public (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens100 ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh zabbix-agent zabbix-server
  ports: 8443/tcp
  protocols: icmp
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

But if I ping from another machine IP of ens192, there is no ICMP on ens100, icmp have only ens192.
Help, What is wrong?

Are you using VMWare? If so, note that some care is needed to correctly configure. Also, iptables tends to be my preferred tool.

When you are creating ens100, instead of ens192 try using the physical interface as the parent.
